# OPTICS algorithm with different epsilons on different axes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, optics-algorithm

I am trying to cluster the supplied charging power to different vehicles.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, AgglomerativeClustering, DBSCAN, OPTICS, cluster_optics_dbscan

df_temp_12 = list(map(lambda x, y: [x, y], VehicleList, Power))
Eps = 1.3
dbscan_12_object = OPTICS(eps=Eps, cluster_method="dbscan")
dbscan_12 = dbscan_12_object.fit_predict(df_temp_12)
```

My present output looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to cluster mainly along the horizontal axis ( as is shown by the cluster in Green). If you notice closely, all other clusters have not been clustered in the same way (i.e. along the horizontal) and hence I am trying to figure out if i can change the EPS value along each axis separately, and if so, how?

EDIT:
After the suggestion by @PlzBePython the output looks like this. Precisely what I needed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKYT9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know that you want to cluster along a specific axis, why not cluster that feature in isolation?

So for example:

```py
data = np.array(Power).reshape((-1, 1))
clusterer = sklearn.cluster.OPTICS(eps=1.3, cluster_method="dbscan")
clustered_data = clusterer.fit(data).labels_
```

Otherwise, I would try creating OPTICS without parameter ([default is to identify clusters across all scales](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.OPTICS.html#sklearn.cluster.OPTICS))

```py
clusterer = sklearn.cluster.OPTICS()
```

or using [Gaussian Mixture](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html#mixture).